# Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, django

`raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.`

i have installed letest postgres setup

psycopg2 installed

[image]

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code. What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: psycopg2 installed

Comment: i'm facing this error if anyone has solution to this help.

Comment: the only way to solve this error is downgrade the python version to second last recent version. for ex 10 is latest version then you have to install 9. and problem solved

Answer (score 6):

I just solve this error by installing second latest python version and to install PostgreSQL use `pip install postgres` this will install psycopg2 & psycopg2-binary

Comment: Thank You so much, I was searching for hours, finally your solution worked.

Comment: A simple and elegant solution. Thank you1

Answer (score 2):

Try to install psycopg2 with:

```
 pip install psycopg2-binary
```

see [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)

Comment: the only way to solve this error is downgrade the python version to second last recent version. for ex 10 is latest version then you have to install 9. and problem solved

Comment: I solved this error by installing second latest python distribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install psycopg2
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve it is to downgrade your python version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33085007)

Answer (score 0):

The fix for my coworker was:

```
pip uninstall psycopg2

pip uninstall psycopg2-binary

pip install psycopg2-binary
```